# How to fetch a user's profile Picture from Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is the PHP ode I am using

```
<?php
session_start();
  include_once "fbconfig.php";
   if($_SESSION["loggedin"] && file_exists("images/dp/$_SESSION[email].jpg"))
    echo "<img src=\"images/dp/$_SESSION[email].jpg\" width=\"100px\">";
?>
```

This is the line to display the image

```
<img class="user_img" src="\images/dp/$_SESSION[email].jpg\" width=\"100px\">
```

Here is the code to fetch other user information

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  $fbid = $user_profile['id'];                 // To Get Facebook ID
    $fbuname = $user_profile['username'];  // To Get Facebook Username
  if(empty($fbuname))
    $fbuname = $user_profile['name']; // To Get Facebook full name
    $femail = $user_profile['email'];    // To Get Facebook email ID
  checkuser($fbid,$fbuname,$femail,'fb');    // To update local DB
  $_SESSION['userId'] = $fbuname;
```

This way the image does not appear where it should? Where am i going wrong?

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/[id]/picture is the link to a profile photo

Comment: Should I place it like this  <img class="user_img" src="graph.facebook.com/$fbid/picture">

Comment: well, there is only one way to find out...

Comment: What was the exact link you tested?

Comment: http://graph.facebook.com/$fbid/picture

Answer (score 0):

add prefix `http://` in img source. i.e. `src="http://graph.facebook.com/$fbid/picture"`

or use the following

`$profile_pic = "https://graph.facebook.com/$fbid/picture";`

so, img `src=" '.$profile_pic.' "`